# how to store array of data in Session and retrieve it Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, session, laravel-5

I was trying to store some data in session through ajax. Means from Ajax request i would get the product_id and it put it inside product array through Session. And I want to retrieve every session array data.

Every Ajax request `product_id` will be stored into Session Array:
// for storing $products into session following controller .But it stored only last one not the previous request

```
public function postEnquote(Request $request)
    {
       $product = Product::where('id',$request->Input(['product_id']))->first();
       Session::put('product', $product);
    }
```

// For retrieving every session data i used following one, but doesn't work properly means i couldn't get every session data..

```
  public function enquoteList()
    {
      foreach(Session::get('product') as $test)
      {
         var_dump($test->id);
      }

     }
```

Comment: Why not just use the `$_SESSION` superglobal directly?

Comment: `Session::put('product', $product);` - you're overwriting this every time, not appending it. If you want multiple products, then you'll have to store it as an array within the session.

Comment: @RobertRocha it's better to use an abstraction so he can swap implementations. If he were to use `$_SESSION` hard-coded like that it'd be a pain to change it all across the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use `push` here.

`Session::push('product', $product);`

So all new `$product` push into `'product'` session variable.

Comment: How do i print that array? means the session array?

Comment: `$products = Session::get('product');` and you can run a `foreach` as `$products` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`push`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#storing-data) to add a value to an array

```
public function postEnquote(Request $request)
{
   $product = Product::where('id',$request->Input(['product_id']))->first();
   Session::push('product', $product);
}
```